# How accurate is the Location information of Geotagged photos?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, geotagging

This question is a bit subjective and not exactly a programming question but very relevant to an idea i am trying to develop.

I want to know the personal opinion and information of developers who have dealt with Geotagged information and what they think is current and what they feel will be possible over next 2-4 years.

SO the question is simple , If i take a picture with an iphone or any other phone with geotagging ability (how far will the next picture have to be to differentiate between the two)

Does the accuracy vary from place to place ? Any comments, opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geolocation data is most likely picked up from the GPS, which is accurate down to a meter or two in the right surroundings.  Tough if you are surrounded by tall buildings it might not be any more accurate than 30-40 meters. I don't know if the phone could use the cell antennas to set the location, if so it'll have an accuracy on perhaps 200-600 meters.

So my conclusion is that is you use your phone with GPS enabled the geotag info is indeed useful and accurate!

Answer (score 3):

I am currently developing geo reading and writing routines to incorporate geo searching as well as picture recognition into my software.

My research using bing maps, google earth and tag viewers only to find that if you take a photo with a mobile phone it seems to be out by up to 1000 meters some times.  I am just starting to look at this but if these are true accuracy levels then this is a concern.  I have only used one mobile phone to date but if these levels are true with other phones then it is a big concern.

I will come back to this page in say a month and maybe some others can give their feedback after using geo tagging on their phone.   I maybe very wrong here but it seems to me that programmers are using different standards than those set out in the EXIF specification.

Comment: interesting ...with the explosion of mosolo apps we will soon find out